# Javascript not working on some (not all) pages built on a Django backend, despite files being found by the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am building a site with Django. I recently have been confronted with an odd issue. The javascript is working on some pages and not others. In fact the one page that does work looks and functions almost identically to one that doesn't.

my html for the page that doesn't work looks like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>MetaScape</title>
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"  rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="{% static 'base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="{% static 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.6.0/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <link href="{% static 'tipsy/src/stylesheets/tipsy.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" >
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class='header'>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="{% url 'uploads.views.home' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="{%url 'IAV.views.IAV_home' %}">IAV</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="{%url 'info.views.view_about'%}">About</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="{%url 'info.views.view_contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 jumbotron" id = "front-jumb">
          <div class="text-left">
            <p>
              Metascape
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="text-right">
            <p id = 'alt'>
              advancing omics analysis
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2" id="one-title">
          <h4>
            Step1:
          </h4>
          <p>
            <FONT FACE="arial">
            Data Processing: 
            Upload Excel file and Download Augmented File
            </FONT>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form action= "{% url 'new_page' %}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2" id="step-one">
            {% load widget_tweaks %}
            {{docform.docfile|attr:"class:filestyle"|attr:"data-classButton:btn btn-primary"|attr:'data-input:false'|attr:'data-classIcon:icon-plus'|attr:'data-buttonText:Upload Data'}}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ docform.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>
              {{ docform.docfile.errors }}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            {{docform.is_multiple}}
            <FONT FACE="arial">Multi Gene List</FONT>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><input id = "process_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Process"/></p>
          </div>
          {% block down %}
          {% endblock %}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% block preview_data %}
    {% endblock %}

    <BR/>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2" id="one-title">
          <h4>
            Step2:
          </h4>
          <p>
            <FONT FACE="arial">
            GO enrichment: 
            Upload Excel file and Download Augmented File
            </FONT>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='container scroll_d2'>
      <div class="row">
        <form action= "{%block go_action %}{%endblock%}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" id="step-one">
            <p style="font-size:90%">Min Overlay</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1" >
            {{goform.overlap}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <p style="font-size:90%">P Value Cutoff</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            {{goform.pvalue}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <p style="font-size:90%">Min Enrichment</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            {{goform.min_enrichment}}
          </div>
          <div class='clearfix'></div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 separate" >
            <dl class="dropdown" title = "Select Any Number Of Flu Proteins. By Default, One or More Selected Proteins Are Matched" id="flu_protein">
              <dt>
                <a>
                  <span class="hida">Select Enrichment Database</span>
                  <p class="multiSel"></p>  
                </a>
              </dt>
              <dd>
                <div class="mutliSelect">
                  <ul>
                    {{goform.select_DB}}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </dd>
            </dl>
          </div>
          <div class='clearfix'></div>

          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 separate" id="step-one">
          {% if document %}
              <div class="file-present">
                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </div>
          {% endif %}

            {{goform.docfile}}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ goform.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>
              {{ goform.docfile.errors }}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <p><input id = "enrich_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enrich"/></p>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/tipsy/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.6.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.6.0/locale/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'upload.js' %}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

the javascript file, that can even be found by clicking the link found by chrome is:

```
var main = function(){

  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.scroll_d2').offset().top }, 2500);

  $('#flu_protein').tipsy({gravity: 'w'});

  $(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function () {
      $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
  });

  $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
      $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });

  function getSelectedValue(id) {
       return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
  }

  $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
      var $clicked = $(e.target);
      if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });


  $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {

      var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
          title = $(this).val() + ",";

      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
          $('.multiSel').append(html);
          $(".hida").hide();
      } 
      else {
          $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
          var ret = $(".hida");
          $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

      }
  });

  $('li').click(function(){
    var current = $('li.active');
    var next = $(this);
    current.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
  });


};
$(document).ready(main)
```

A very similar page that does work has the HTML of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>MetaScape</title>
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"  rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="{% static 'base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="{% static 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.6.0/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <link href="{% static 'tipsy/src/stylesheets/tipsy.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" >
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class='header'>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="{% url 'uploads.views.home' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="{%url 'IAV.views.IAV_home'%}">IAV</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="{%url 'info.views.view_about'%}">About</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="{%url 'info.views.view_contact'%}">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 jumbotron" id = "front-jumb">
          <div class="text-left">
            <p>
              Metascape
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="text-right">
            <p id = 'alt'>
              advancing omics analysis
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2" id="one-title">
          <h4>
            Step1:
          </h4>
   </h4>
          <p>
            <FONT FACE="arial">
            Data Processing:
            Upload Excel file and Download Augmented File
            </FONT>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form action= "{% url 'new_page' %}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2" id="step-one">
            {% load widget_tweaks %}
            {{docform.docfile|attr:"class:filestyle"|attr:"data-classButton:btn btn-primary"|attr:'data-input:false'|attr:'data-classIcon:icon-plus'|attr:'data-buttonText:Upload Data'}}
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ docform.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>
              {{ docform.docfile.errors }}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            {{docform.is_multiple}}
            <FONT FACE="arial">Multi Gene List</FONT>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <p><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Process"/></p>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <BR/>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2" id="one-title">
          <h4>
            Step2:
          </h4>
          <p>
            <FONT FACE="arial">
            GO enrichment:
            Upload Excel file and Download Augmented File
            </FONT>
          </p>
        </div>
</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form action= "{% block go_action%}{%endblock%}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" id="step-one">
            <p style="font-size:90%">Min Overlay</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1" >
            {{goform.overlap}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <p style="font-size:90%">P Value Cutoff</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            {{goform.pvalue}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <p style="font-size:90%">Min Enrichment</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            {{goform.min_enrichment}}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3" >
            <dl class="dropdown" title = "Select Any Number Of Flu Proteins. By Default, One or More Selected Proteins Are Matched" id="flu_protein">
              <dt>
                <a>
                  <span class="hida">Select Enrichment Database</span>
                  <p class="multiSel"></p>
                </a>
              </dt>
              <dd>
                  <div class="mutliSelect">
                      <ul>
                          {{goform.select_DB}}
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </dd>
            </dl>
          </div>

          <div class='clearfix'></div>

          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 separate" id="step-one">
            <!--{{goform.docfile}}-->
            {% csrf_token %}
 <p>{{ goform.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>
              {{ goform.docfile.errors }}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1 separate">
            {% if img %}
            <p><input class="btn btn-primary disable_enrich enrich_button" type="submit" value="Enrich"/></p>
            {% else %}
            <p><input class="btn btn-primary enrich_button" type="submit" value="Enrich"/></p>

            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
    <BR/>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="row col-md-10 col-md-offset-2" >
        <img src="/media/{{img}}"/>
        <!--
        <table data-toggle="table">
          {% for el in postings %}
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  {{el}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
        -->
      </div>
      {% block go_down %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>



    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/tipsy/src/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.6.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.6.0/locale/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'enrich.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the javascript for this page looks like:

```
var main = function(){

  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('.scroll_d1').offset().top }, 2500);

  $('#flu_protein').tipsy({gravity: 'w'});

  $(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function () {
      $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
  });

  $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
      $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });

  function getSelectedValue(id) {
       return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
  }

  $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
      var $clicked = $(e.target);
      if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });


  $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {

      var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
          title = $(this).val() + ",";

      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
          $('.multiSel').append(html);
          $(".hida").hide();
      } 
      else {
          $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
          var ret = $(".hida");
          $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

      }
  });


  $('li').click(function(){
    var current = $('li.active');
    var next = $(this);
    current.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
  });


};
$(document).ready(main)
```

I had even made the two javascript files as similar as possible to see if the problem was the javscript or not.

Comment: have you tried managing static files via `django.contrib.staticfiles` instead of hard wiring the paths?

Comment: @DejaVu yes I am already doing this. This is how Chrome interprets the templates. I thought that may be more helpful. Would it be more helpful to post the original templates?

Comment: yes, please, edit and post original, and include the names of your files

Comment: @DejaVu Okay I changed the post

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to find any syntax issues, except maybe missing semicolons at the end of `js`, do you think you can "narrow down" what exactly doesn't work? For example in your working `js` you target `scroll_d1` but no such class in your `html`.

Comment: @DejaVu The part with the dropdown class is not clickable. The tipsy package is not funtioning to display help boxes. Additionally, even after replacing scroll_d1 with scroll_d2, it does not move down the screen.

Comment: Any errors in the browser's javascript console? CTRL + SHIFT + J in chrome. Can you check that all javascript sources were loaded properly under the sources tab?